# Validity of non-problematic questions

Tags: feature-request, questions

I often come across questions that are simply points of curiosity rather than requests for help to overcome a development problem that is blocking progress.

Examples of these might be *“Why is the number of bits in a word always a power of two?“* or *"What kind of parsing engine does Perl use?"*.

While these examples may fall foul of the rules for other reasons, I can see nothing in the list of reasons to close a question that covers such idle curiosity.

Have I missed something, or should a new category be added?

Comment: “What does BASIC stand for?” is off-topic; belongs on Wiktionary.

Comment: @minitechη: As I said, those example questions may also fall foul of other rules, but there are questions of this type for which I cannot see an exclusion rule.

Comment: offtopic appears to be about [language design] or [history of software development] or the like. Failing that, opinion based would work for me.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you think the problems are with your two examples or questions like them? Why are you looking for a reason to close them?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I am looking at the Help Centre rules which say, *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"*. My understanding is that Stack Overflow is about *resolving problems*, and questions of this sort, where there is no "problem" as such and the question is a matter of philosophy, don't belong here. It does seem to be a specific and common category of question that shouldn't be forced under another heading. Please can someone correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think you're taking those Help Center rules overly literally. They're meant as a general guideline because *most* good questions will fall under those guidelines. I don't think they're meant to *exclude* good programming questions. Both of the examples you've given here would be perfectly acceptable. I would fight strongly against any attempt to close them. You have to evaluate each question independently, based on its coherence and ability to be *answered*. The only thing we feel strongly about is that **good questions have an answer**. Not multiple valid answers, not mere speculation.

Comment: @minitech what would the close reason be? That's why these new ones suck

Comment: @ColeJohnson: It would be the custom “off-topic” one, but yes, I agree that we’re lacking a couple important reasons at the moment.

Comment: @CodyGray: In that case the Help Center rules need revising. There needs to be a definition of available questions that we can take *completely* literally.

Answer (score 1):

There's always the Off Topic->Other option, if you want to elaborate on it.

In this case, I'd probably mark it as such (eg. "is about software trivia", or something like that.), and leave a comment pointing to the Wikipedia page for BASIC, or similar.

Comment: OK I've removed that example as it seemd to be misleading people

Comment: I'd say that kind of thing still falls under the list of things [one shouldn't be asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), or questions that should likely be asked elsewhere. The first example could possibly be asked on [su] (where some similar questions exist, eg. http://superuser.com/q/235030). As for the second, I might still suggest closing as off-topic, as one could check the source, and a short search will likely come up with the answer.

Comment: @Hasturkun I'm curious why you think that a question is "off topic" because its answer can be found with "a short search". Can't the answer to nearly *all* Stack Overflow questions be found with a short search? The only exception would be "debug my code"-style questions, but surely you don't want the site to become a debugging service. I certainly don't.

Comment: @CodyGray: I don't think a question would be off topic for being found by a short search. I think those specific examples are (with the removed BASIC example being one); And if/when voting to close them, I normally point out the relevant resource (generally found by a ~3 minute search).